# Connecting Ms Access Db to Mysql through Vba

Tags: mysql, vba, server

I have been trying to connect `mysql database` to `ms Access` but no result.I don't think personally I am using the `DAo.Connection` and the `workspace` properly. I keep on getting the 3001 connection error when I set `mySqlCon`. I guess my arguments are not properly set but I was following an example from [here](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1637493).

```
Function connectingMySql()
   Dim mySqlCon As Dao.Connection
   Dim wrkODBC As Workspace

   Set wrkODBC = CreateWorkspace("newODBCWorkspace", "admin", "", dbUseODBC)

   Set mySqlCon = wrkODBC.OpenConnection("connection1", , , "DRIVER={MYSQL ODBC 5.1 DRIVER};" _
   & "SERVER=testserver.com;port=3306;" _
   & "DATABASE=test;" _
   & "USER=root;" _
   & "PASSWORD=pass;" _
   & "Option=3;")
End Function
```

More infos:

- Running Ms Access 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggle, I fixed it. Basically my arguments where wrong. Now I am getting a connection Error, which means the argument error has been fixed.

```
Function connectingMySql()
   Dim mySqlCon As Dao.Connection
   Dim wrkODBC As Workspace

   Set wrkODBC = CreateWorkspace("newODBCWorkspace", "admin", "", dbUseODBC)

   Set mySqlCon = wrkODBC.OpenConnection("DRIVER={MYSQL ODBC 5.1 DRIVER};" _
   & "SERVER=testserver.com;port=3306;" _
   & "DATABASE=test;" _
   & "USER=root;" _
   & "PASSWORD=pass;" _
   & "Option=3;")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821374(v=office.14).aspx) says that using `dbUseODBC` will cause a runtime error.

> ODBCDirect workspaces are not supported in Microsoft Access 2010. Setting the type argument to dbUseODBC will result in a run-time error. Use ADO if you want to access external data sources without using the Microsoft Access database engine.

Try `Set wrkODBC = CreateWorkspace("newODBCWorkspace", "admin", "")`