# Is is possible to I sync data from MS access VB to mysql database

Tags: mysql, laravel, ms-access

I got one project that customer need to sync data from Microsoft Access to mySQL on cloud server.

Now customer has form on Microsoft Access when they click save button, it will call function to save data to local database.

[image]

What they want to do is once customer click save button, t will call the same function and also send data to mysql on cloud server as well.

Anyone know how to do this or any idea how to solve this case.

Regards.

Comment: You could set it up so it also sends the data via post to a laravel route. Then you can just save it with laravel. Alternatively, i *think* you can have VB open a new connection to your MySQL db and just have it input the data.

Comment: Do you have any sample how to open new connection on VB. Because I'm not familiar with VB. Thank you

Comment: Code should be posted as text, not image.

Comment: the best i can do to help is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650601/connecting-ms-access-db-to-mysql-through-vba

I despise access VB, and have little knowledge of it.